# How do I split cost using Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

So, I have a web application that is built using Ruby on Rails and VueJS where people can order food and I'm currently using Stripe as the payment gateway. Currently, users can select which meal they like and select how many guests so it multiplies the cost by number of guests then proceed to pay for it via CC on our platform. We're using Stripe "managed accounts".

What I would like to accomplish though is, if a user selects 2 guests then they have the option to pay for it themselves or pay for their half and then have the other guest pay for their half. Essentially we'd like the ability to divide the payments amongst the guests as an option.

How can we accomplish this using Stripe?

Comment: Hi... this is a very broad question. You are asking us to design your payment system for you. Generally Stack overflow works by you having a go at it, then coming to us when you have a specific, technical problem (a good gauge is if the question has a definite, single "right" answer). How about you have a go at it and see what you can come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's API does not have any facilities for this specific scenario: a charge with Stripe has a single payment source.

If you want to split the bill between multiple customers, it's up to you to [create as many charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) as needed, with the right amounts.

If you do this, keep in mind that it's possible that some of the charges will succeed and others will fail. You might want to use the [auth & capture](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture) flow to first create authorizations, and only capture them if all the authorizations succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!